# I get all the rows of the third columns "ones" !!

Tags: c#, button, datagridview

I have a dataGridView and a button,when I clic the button the thrid cell of each row contains the value "1" but I want that only the lines that contain data should contains "1"
in the third column. 
I tried this code to test before making the ones but the result is shown in the image:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("" + dt.Year.ToString() + "", "En cours", "0");


            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // int ik = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row1.Cells)
                        {
                            if (cell.Value != null)
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = 1;
                            }
                            else  //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( cell.Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                break;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the result:
[image]

thanks for Help

Comment: I want that every row in the dataGridView contains the value "1" in the third  column ,only the lines that contain data ,but for the other empty lines (cell.value==null it is necessary to put "1") :)

Comment: I need help please :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("" + dt.Year.ToString() + "", "En cours", "0");


            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // int ik = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row1.Cells)
                        {
                            string st = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                            if (cell.Value == null && st == "0")
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = 1;                                
                            }
                            else  //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( cell.Value.ToString()))
                            {                                
                                break;                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```

**Edit**

I'm not sure that some things should be done this way like you did and what is the outcome of this project. But I modified and debug the code it is working now,  I hope it will help

Comment: thanks Dusan but with the counter When I try de debug the code,the debugger can't access the "if condition" dispite the rows are not empty thanks for your help again

Comment: I'am sorry Dusan but it doesn't help me :(